# C++ lambda macro to force argument type

Tags: c++, lambda, macros, type-conversion

Going through cdda's opensource codebase I found a pretty funky looking macro that I'd like to understand better

Macro definition

```
/**
*  The purpose of this macro is to provide a concise syntax for
*  creation of inline literals (std::string, string_id, etc) that
*  also have static scope.
*
*  Usage:
*    instead of:  some_method( "string_constant" );
*    use:         some_method( STATIC ( "string_constant" ) );
*
*    instead of:  some_method( string_id<T>( "id_constant" ) );
*    use:         some_method( STATIC ( string_id<T>( "id_constant" ) ) );
*
*    const V &v = STATIC( expr );
*    // is an equivalent of:
*    static const V v = expr;
*
*    Note: `expr` being char* (i.e. "a string literal") is a special case:
*      for such type of argument,  STATIC(expr) has `const std::string &` result type.
*      This is to support expressions like STATIC("...") instead of STATIC(std::string("..."))
*/
```

The Macro with my comments trying to clarify what each bit is doing

```
//Forces a type 
template<typename T>
inline const T &static_argument_identity( const T &t ){
    return t;
}

#define STATIC(expr) \
    (\
        ([]()-> const auto &{ \
                /*Get the type and convert to typedef */ \
                using ExprType = std::decay_t<decltype(static_argument_identity( expr ))>; \
\
                /*Specail logic to make string literals std::strings, else leave it alone */ \
                using CachedType = std::conditional_t<std::is_same<ExprType, const char*>::value, std::string, ExprType>; \
\
                /*Reassign the type */ \
                static const CachedType _cached_expr = static_argument_identity( expr ); \
\
                return _cached_expr; \
            }\
        )()\
    )
```

So if we were to use the int 5, this would equate to:

```
[]()-> const auto&{return const int&(5)}()
```

And if we use "Hello", this would equate to

```
[]()-> const auto&{return const std::String&("Hello")}()
```

**Questions**

Why does static_argument_identity need to be used in:

```
using ExprType = std::decay_t<decltype(static_argument_identity( expr ))>;
```

Why doesn't this throw? Does this do implicit conversion from "Hello" to std::String("Hello")

```
const std::String &static_argument_identity( const std::string &t ){
    return t;
}
```

Why does the lambda have the "()" after it? Is the execute call for the function?

-> const auto&{return ...}**()**

And finally would the compiler compile all these out to just constant variables, since it's a pretty straight forward conversion?

Comment: `[]() { }()` means to define a lambda which is immediately called. This is a trick to use _statements_ (and declarations and definitions) where an _expression_ is accepted only. Your sample for `5` is not quite exact. It would expand to `[]() -> const auto& { static const int _cached_expr = 5; return _cached_expr; }();` The whole sense of that `STATIC` macro is to turn a simple expressions into a value which is stored in a static variable (i.e. with life-time until end of process) and can be referred to with a `const` reference.

Comment: Oh I see I totally missed the "static const" part of "static const CachedType _cached_expr = static_argument_identity( expr );". Sorry realized the answer below is you that I'm about to read. Thanks for the detail reply, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked

> Why does the lamda have the "()" after it? Is the execute call for the function?

Yes. This is the definition of a lambda which is immediately called. Hence, the whole forms an expression and can be used where expressions (of compatible type) are expected.

Nevertheless, the lambda's body can contain everything what's allowed in every function body i.e. declarations, definitions, and statements.

---

The expanded sample code for `5` provided by OP is not quite correct.
More correct would be:

```
[]() -> const auto& {
  static const int _cached_expr = 5;
  return _cached_expr;
}()
```

This leads to the question: What is the advantage of storing a literal in a `static` variable which lives until end of process?

If a value is provided where a const reference is expected, the value will be wrapped into a temporary. For repeated calls this will be a new temporary for each invocation.

It's not clear to me under which conditions this might be undesired. However, the `STATIC` macro with its lambda magic turns a value into a `static` variable so that a const reference to the always same instance can be provided.

It's a bit difficult to illustrate this with a plain `int` literal. Hence, I used a sample `struct` with an unique `id` to be able to distinguish instances.

The effect of `STATIC` illustrated in an [MCVE (on coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ab74a21f5fc875b):

```
#include <iostream>

//Forces a type 
template<typename T>
inline const T &static_argument_identity( const T &t ){
    return t;
}

#define STATIC(expr) \
    (\
        ([]()-> const auto &{ \
                /*Get the type and convert to typedef */ \
                using ExprType = std::decay_t<decltype(static_argument_identity( expr ))>; \
\
                /*Specail logic to make string literals std::strings, else leave it alone */ \
                using CachedType = std::conditional_t<std::is_same<ExprType, const char*>::value, std::string, ExprType>; \
\
                /*Reassign the type */ \
                static const CachedType _cached_expr = static_argument_identity( expr ); \
\
                return _cached_expr; \
            }\
        )()\
    )

struct Value {
  static inline unsigned id = 0;
  const int value;

  Value(int value): value(value) { ++id; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Value& value)
{
  return out << "Value { " << value.value << " } #" << value.id;
}

void f(const Value& value)
{
  std::cout << "f(" << value << ")\n";
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ ; std::cout << '\n'

int main()
{
  DEBUG(for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) f(Value(123)));
  DEBUG(for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) f(STATIC(Value(123))));
}
```

Output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) f(Value(123));
f(Value { 123 } #1)
f(Value { 123 } #2)
f(Value { 123 } #3)

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) f(STATIC(Value(123)));
f(Value { 123 } #4)
f(Value { 123 } #4)
f(Value { 123 } #4)
```

In the first loop, each call of `f()` is invoked with a new instance of `Value`.

In opposition, in the second loop `f()` is always invoked with the same instance of `Value`. Hence, it's not only an equal object — it's the exact same object which is "received" in `f()`.

Unfortunately, I must admit that I'm not aware where this difference might be important although I remember another question (this or last year) where this difference was required.

---

Concerning

```
template<typename T>
inline const T &static_argument_identity( const T &t ){
    return t;
}
```

I assume that it's used to turn (the type of) an expression into a const reference.
If it already was a const reference it stays a const reference.
If it was not a const reference it becomes a const reference.

For the sample of OP:

`5` has the type `int`.

Hence, for `static_argument_identity(5)`, the compile deduces:

```
inline const int& static_argument_identity(const int& t) { return t; }
```

and `decltype(static_argument_identity( expr ))` will return `const int&`.

[std::decay](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) removes all cv qualifiers and the reference to unwrap the inner type.

I must admit that I'm not that confident in template programming to explain why it's necessary to turn something into a const reference (for sure) to unwrap the basic type afterwards.

```
std::decay_t<decltype(expr)>
```

should have the same effect — but maybe only for certain types but not all.

Comment: `static_argument_identity()` is probably to prevent moves into the variable (I mean the actual call outside of the typedef). And inside the typedef it's used merely for consistency.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I must admit this is not my strongest skill. I took your _move_ literally and fiddled a bit on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/749b0c3c7312a7e0) but failed to find a counter example where `static_argument_identity()` makes a difference. :-(

Comment: Something like `std::string a = "foo"; const std::string &b = STATIC(std::move(a));`. Though I'm unsure why somebody would want to ban this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Even this didn't make a difference: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92f804266c6717af). As this is part of a library, the author may have addressed a subtle corner case I'm not aware of... (...and probably never will face in daily business.) ;-)

Comment: OP doesn't have `decay_t` in `static const CachedType _cached_expr = static_argument_identity( expr );`. A fair comparison would be `decltype(expr)` vs `decltype(static_argument_identity(expr))`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry, I don't get it. `CachedType` is either `std::string` or `ExprType`. `ExprType` is `std::decay_t<decltype(static_argument_identity( expr ))>`. Why not simply `std::decay_t<decltype(expr)>`? This is where I failed to find a counter example where the former and latter would differ...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Sorry! I might not have explained that well, but I wrote all the comments in the code when I was trying to figure out what it did. I may be entirely wrong >_<

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks for the detailed reply, it helps a lot. To the lambda, don't you sometimes pass the lamda to a function rather than executing it? And to the decay, maybe it's to avoid the final output being const const type& which the compiler would not be happy about.

Comment: @Justin Of course, my primary use of lambdas is to make local adapters so that the call of one function fits into the required signature of something else. They are also nice to provide little predicates (e.g. in `std::sort()`). And finally, a named lambda fills a gap in C++: local functions (to some extent). The immediately-called-lambda-trick, I use less often but it helps e.g. to make more complex argument transformations in constructors. Last but not least, an immediately called lambda can be used for complex init. of `const` variables, and to replace the old `do { } while (false)` idiom.